# Can I download Bamboo built artifacts using Bamboo Rest - API?

Tags: rest, bamboo, continuous-delivery

[This](https://developer.atlassian.com/bamboodev/rest-apis) page states:

> Bamboo's REST APIs provide the following capabilities:
>
> - Retrieve the artifacts for a build.

and [here](https://docs.atlassian.com/bamboo/REST/5.8.0/) I see the documentation:

> http://myhost.com:8085/bamboo/rest/api/latest/plan/{projectKey}-{buildKey}/artifact
>   [GET]

When I try this link with the bamboo server I have, like:

```
https://my.bamboo.server/rest/api/latest/plan/MY-PLAN/artifact
```

All I get is:

```
<artifacts expand="artifacts">
    <link href="http://my.bamboo.server/rest/api/latest/plan/MY-PLAN/artifact" rel="self"/>
    <artifacts start-index="0" max-result="0" size="0"/>
</artifacts>
```

So am I understanding the REST documentation completely wrong, or is there something wrong possibly with MY-PLAN and this link is supposed to provide me a war file as I expect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid you are misunderstanding the REST documentation; by "Retrieve the artifacts for a build", it means "retrieves information about the build artifacts defined for a given plan".  As you have already seen, all you get back is an XML or JSON document describing the artifacts defined.

If you want to download an actual build artifact, you'll need to write a script that uses /rest/api/latest/result/ to get the latest successful build info and, from that, form an actual download link to the artifact.

Comment: This is where I get lost: "from that, form an actual download link to the artifact." Which parts of the results to use and how to put it all together to form a link?

Comment: The above gets you the specific <project_key>-<plan_key>_<build_number> (e.g. from "buildResultKey").  The rest of the link you'll have to create yourself, but presumably you know the artifact name and path?

Comment: @RCross Unfortunately, that is useless for automation, unless you get an API URL to the artifact Log In won't work using the default URL(at least not in the current Bamboo's setup) a 301 is fired and the http parser is redirected to the bamboo login URL, EVEN if you pass login parameters in the headers. So all you get is the welcome log in prompt when you do a GET artifact-url.  I will try and via rest and update this comment AND thanks for the interpretation about the meaning of the document. That saved me time.

Answer (score 2):

There are some issues related to your question: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-11706
and BAM-16315 (which was deleted, because it contained customer details)

Comment: BAM-16315 can't be viewed right now, can you adjust the issue security so that we can follow along?

Comment: BAM-16315 contained customer's details, it was closed as duplicate of BAM-11706

Answer (score 2):

Here is the rest api documentation

```
https://docs.atlassian.com/atlassian-bamboo/REST/latest
```

Search for "/latest/result" documentation

```
http://myhost.com:8085/rest/api/latest/result/{projectKey}-{buildKey}-{buildNumber : ([0-9]+)|(latest)} [GET]
```

Example xml request

```
https://bamboo.server.com/rest/api/latest/result/projectKey-buildKey-buildNumber?expand=artifacts
```

Example json request

```
https://bamboo.server.com/rest/api/latest/result/projectKey-buildKey-buildNumber.json?expand=artifacts
```

Parse the artifacts node in the response. Each artifact should have an href property.
Pass the href to curl to download the artifact. You will probably need to setup a Bamboo token for rest api authentication.

Example curl request

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer ${BAMBOO_TOKEN}" $ARTIFACT_HREF
```

Comment: not working, it seems the bearer can only be use with the rest api

Comment: you have to use user and password to download your file

curl -X GET -uuser:pass $ARTIFACT_HREF -o output.ext

Answer (score 0):

Spent a long time looking for this answer. Ended up having to piece together information and here is what I got. As @oallauddin mentions above, you need to get the url of the file from the xml.

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <KEY>" https://bamboo.server.com/rest/api/latest/result/projectKey-buildKey-buildNumber?expand=artifacts
```

Alternative you can get it as json format

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <KEY>" https://bamboo.server.com/rest/api/latest/result/projectKey-buildKey-buildNumber.json?expand=artifacts
```

I think where a lot of people are getting stuck is trying to use the Authorization header to download it after. [BAM-20764](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-20764) shows that this is NOT possible. You have to remove the header and use basic authentication with -u. Not both. Only the -u by itself.

```
curl -u username:password https://bamboo.server.com/browse/projectKey-build-Key-buildNumber/artifact/shared/<ARTIFACT_NAME>/<filename> --remote-name
```

The --remote-name/-O flag or --remote-header-name/-J is preferred here if you want to download the file with the default original name.

Answer (score -2):

You've the link

```
<link href="http://my.bamboo.server/rest/api/latest/plan/MY-PLAN/artifact" rel="self"/>
```

Using curl you can download the artifact.

```
curl --user ${username}:{password} http://my.bamboo.server/rest/api/latest/plan/MY-PLAN/artifact
```

Comment: This doesn't download the artifact; it simply downloads an XML/JSON document (XML by default) describing the artifacts available.

Comment: can you try like this
 `curl -O -L --user ${username}:{password} http://my.bamboo.server/rest/api/latest/plan/MY-PLAN/artifact`

Comment: I can, but the result is exactly the same.  It simply downloads some XML that shows the location/name of the artifact file.  It does not download the artifact itself.