# Bamboo Trigger Deployment plan with variables

Tags: bamboo

Im trying to deploy a plan that has artefacts from external service for this I want to download via curl those files that I will pass as variables... however I am not able to set programmaticly the variables with the deploymet call

```
curl -k -u user:passord -X POST -d "bamboo.myVariable=someurl" BASE_BAMBOO_URL/bamboo/rest/api/latest/queue/PROJECT-ID
```

Trying to do the same with the deployment API fails

```
curl BASE_BAMBOO_URL/bamboo/rest/api/latest/deploy/project/1321123123 -u user:passord-X POST -d "bamboo.myVariable=callMEwithDATA"
```

Trying to add that into the API fails as does trying to pass it thru JSON

```
curl -X POST BASE_BAMBOO/bamboo/rest/api/latest/deploy/project/1320058 -u user:passord -H "Accepts: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name":"release-1", "myVariable":"ARTEFACT_URL"}'
```

Comment: You might be able to use: `BASE_BAMBOO_URL/browse/<buildResultKey>/artifact/shared/<name_of_the_artifact>`. Not the most beautiful solution though, but it works if you know the `buildResultKey`. You should be able to find it programmatically using the REST API.
You can properly find some inspiration here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39072200/can-i-download-bamboo-built-artifacts-using-bamboo-rest-api)

Comment: hum that is not what i was asking i want to set variables any kin of variable like i do for a build plan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To continue with a request the variables have to be passed as query params... a sad sad reality is that the Bamboo API is very messed up

bamboourl&executeAllStages=true&bamboo.variable.MYVAR=1234